# Reactor jumping to the wrong Scheduler?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I've got a flux I'm processing in steps using flatMaps and calling blocking code with a Mono.fromCallable(). When looking in the run logs, the retires are running in the parallel pool for some reason. Why is that, and how can I get them to execute in the scheduler that the group is running on? This is basically the workflow below, starting with a stream of messages, group by some key, then for each group, I want to run them in their own Scheduler with a max concurrency of 6 (in this case). What am I doing wrong?

```
messageStream
    .groupBy(this::grouper)
    .flatMap(group ->
        Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newBoundedElastic(6, 1, "ChildPool:"+group.key());
        return group
              .publishOn(scheduler)
              .flatMap(t1 -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> chevronOne(t1))
                   .retryBackoff(MAX_RETRIES, Duration.ofSeconds(1), Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                    .onErrorResume(e -> doErrorChevronOne(m, e, t1))
              )
              .flatMap(t2 -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> chevronTwo(t2))
                   .retryBackoff(MAX_RETRIES, Duration.ofSeconds(1), Duration.ofSeconds(60))
                   .onErrorResume(e -> doErrorChevronOne(m, e, t2))
               )
```

Here are a couple of lines from the logs showing the Scheduler jumping:

```
2020-08-12 15:33:20.289 INFO [ChildPool:1004-21] e.u.t.t.f.l.transfers.ITestTransfers:582
2020-08-12 15:33:20.889 INFO [parallel-2] e.u.t.t.f.l.s.TransfersService:475 - ***** DOING chevronTwo ****
```

Answer (score 1):

`publishOn` only guarantees that given `Scheduler` will be used by the following operator. `retryBackoff` schedules the retry on the `parallel` scheduler by default, hence the result.

You **must always** be explicit about the scheduling if you need to handle something on a specific `Scheduler`.